# Possible to manually set ID of new rows with RedBean PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using RedBean PHP to dump some data from a web scrape into a database, and I need to retain the legacy IDs, preferably as the primary key field. Is it possible to do this with RedBean?

When I try to set the id as so:

```
$bean->id = 56;
```

The row doesn't get inserted - the query that ends up being created instead becomes an "UPDATE WHERE `id`=56", which does nothing since the record doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forcing a specific value on an auto-increment primary index is just asking for race-condition problems. I'd suggest you create a new column `legacy_id` instead where you save the alternative id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to turn off auto_increment on the tables that RedBean creates? I'm never going to be creating records without explicitly specifying an ID. I thinking this may be out of the scope of RedBean.

Comment: @jord Possibly, but I have no experience with RedBean, sorry. Generally I find it easier to let the database do its auto-incrementing to give me a guaranteed good index and do my own stuff in other columns.

Comment: Sometimes people have requirements such as one-to-one mapping between tables, where auto_increment is not used.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by inserting a placeholder with an SQL exec first:

```
    $id = 60000;
    $name = 'bob';

    R::exec('insert into person(id) values('.$id.')');
    $person = R::dispense('person');
    $person->id = $id;
    $person->name = $name;
    R::store($person);
```

Comment: I think it is crappy that Redbean doesn't allow you to use your own ids. I am using custom ids this is going to seriously worry me, but thanks for your solution. works ok.

Comment: I just hit a problem where if I had a not null column this doesn't work so looking for another solution now.

Comment: Then use a placeholder value. Btw, Eloquent is a better way to go now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I use Laravel and Eloquent for large websites and you gave me the idea to see if it can be used to make console apps, it can but seems like overkill for the simple database scripts I write with readbean, I like how portable it is to just copy a single php file between servers.

Comment: Good one ! I just use the `R::findOne()` or `R::load()` instead of `R::dispense()`, after manual `R::exec('INSERT ...')`, semantically at least it seems better ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I have started an **redbean github** project for this, first version supports to have custom id fields.

You have to tell redbean what the name of the id field is (if not "`id`")

```
R::getRedBean()->idFieldMap= array('adres'=>'id_adres','contact'=>'contact_id'); // settings for current database
```

Future improvements: support custom Foreign keys.

https://github.com/freelanceniek/redbeanx