# Using a FOR loop with RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, database, loops, orm, redbean

```
// Includes rb.php here etc.
$mail_type = array('gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yandex.ru', 'hotmail.com', 'live.no');

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $mail = R::dispense('emails');
    $mail->id = $i;

    // Create random email
    $mail->email = strtolower(substr(base64_encode(mt_rand(99, 99999)), 0, -2)).'@'.$mail_type[mt_rand(0, 4)];

    R::store($mail);
    unset($mail); // This doesn't work either
}
```

Trying to insert 100 different randomly made e-mails with RedBeanPHP. For some reason I can't get this to work since only the last object gets inserted into the database, effectively replacing the last. Can't find any documentation on it either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedBeanPHP thinks it's already stored since you set the id. Solution is to remove the $mail->id = $id field.

Comment: That makes sense. The `R::store` only inserts a new auto incremented row if no ID was specified. Thanks.

Comment: Forcing a specific value on an auto-increment primary index is just asking for race-condition problems (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101487/possible-to-manually-set-id-of-new-rows-with-redbean-php )

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that $mail is being instantiated with the emails but not storing to R? I'm not sure what R is, but if its an array of objects I could expand further. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: `R::` is a static reference to the **RedBeanPHP ORM**. `R::Store` will save the object stored in the `$mail` variable to the database.

Comment: Well from your explanation I think your code looks good. Did you try printing out the results of the for loop before hitting to the Database? If it's returning what you want then the problem lies in the Database or your R object.